# SQL join table first with match and then unmatched values

Tags: sql, sql-server

Following are two tables.
I want to first join them with an exact match and then unmatching values.

[image]

**I need output like below.**

[image]

```
drop table if exists #C
CREATE TABLE #C(CustNo varchar(100), TranID varchar (100))
insert into #C values

('A','A123'),
('A','A456'),
('A','A586'),
('B','B36')

drop table if exists #D
CREATE TABLE #D(VCustNo varchar(100), VTransID varchar (100))
INSERT INTO #D VALUES
('A','A123'),
('A','A456'),
('A','A555'), 
('A','A858'), 
('C','C469')
```

Comment: use full join to get the result

Comment: that does not work with required output

Comment: What is the rational behind the third result row, matching TransID A586 to VtransID A555? How should your code decide which of the unmatched values go together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit complicated.  You want matches side-by-side.  Then you want mismatches ordered independently.  I recommend `union all` for the two different cases:

```
select a.custno as custno, a.transId, b.vtransId
from a join
     b
     on a.custno = b.vcustno and a.transId = b.vtransId
union all
select custno, max(TransId), max(vTransId)
from (select coalesce(a.CustNo, b.vCustNo) as custno, a.TransId, b.VTransId, 
             row_number() over (partition by coalesce(a.custno, b.vcustno),
                                             case when a.TransId is null then 1 else 2 end, 
                                             case when b.vTransId is null then 1 else 2 end
                                order by TransId) as seqnum
      from a full join
           b
           on a.custno = b.vcustno and a.transId = b.vtransId
      where a.custno is null or b.vcustno is null
     ) ab
group by custno, seqnum
order by custno;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1d4da09fc8a599e2ed13bdacc58ee6af) is a db<>fiddle.

You can also phrase this without `union all`, but I think the above is easier to follow:

```
select custno, max(TransId), max(vTransId)
from (select coalesce(a.CustNo, b.vCustNo) as custno, a.TransId, b.VTransId, 
             row_number() over (partition by coalesce(a.custno, b.vcustno)
                                order by case when a.TransId is not null and b.vTransId is null then 1
                                              when b.vTransId is null then 2 else 3
                                         end) as seqnum
      from a full join
           b
           on a.custno = b.vcustno and a.transId = b.vtransId
     ) ab
group by custno, seqnum
order by custno;
```